# Why was my comment deleted?

Tags: discussion

This question is meant to gather a list of general reasons why a comment would be deleted.

So I made the following comment in a question regarding, [What are the main arguments against White Nationalism?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/23643/what-are-the-main-arguments-against-white-nationalism)

> No sources, opinion, so leaving as comment. Typically Whites are seen as more powerful in western society and Western society is typically viewed as "White society" by those that are sympathetic or with less power. As such the notion of White Nationalism tends to be viewed more a racial cleansing as opposed to Black Nationalism or Asian Nationalism that is viewed typically as an equality movement because they do not view these groups as in charge or powerful. I'd recommend reading up on Marx's ideas of class struggles to understand it a bit more

The mod told me I was trying to leave an answer, which reading the comment is false as opinions are typically not given weight as answers. I was also told that it was due to edits to the question, but the comment was deleted prior to the edits.

So my question is what are the general factors that will lead to comment deletion on Politics Exchange?

Comment: Really curious about why this is getting down voted as it is proven that the given reason is/was/continue to be a lie or wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [help center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), the purpose of comments is:

> •Request **clarification** from the author;
>
> •Leave **constructive criticism**
> that guides the author in improving the post;
>
> •Add relevant but **minor
> or transient information** to a post (e.g. a link to a related question,
> or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

<sub>(emphasis present in source)</sub>

Any comments which do not or no longer fulfill these three purposes are subject to deletion. All users are encouraged to flag such comments as "no longer needed".

The same article also provides a list of situations when Comments should **not** be posted:

> Comments are not recommended for any of the following:
>
> •**Suggesting corrections** that don't fundamentally change the meaning of
> the post; instead, make or suggest an edit;
>
> •**Answering a question** or providing an alternate solution to an
> existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an
> existing one);
>
> •**Compliments** which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!");
> instead, up-vote it and pay it forward;
>
> •**Criticisms** which do not add anything constructive ("-1, see previous
> comments you scallywag!"); instead, down-vote (and provide or up-vote
> a better answer if appropriate);
>
> •**Secondary discussion** or debating a controversial point; please use
> chat instead;
>
> •**Discussion of community behavior** or site policies; please use meta
> instead.

The points 2 and 5 are relevant in this case.

**Comments are not meant to answer questions**. That's what answers are for. If you would like to answer the question, please post a real answer which adheres to our quality standards. One reason for this rule is that some users (I don't want to accuse the author of this meta-question to be one of them) abuse the fact that comments can be upvoted but not downvoted. That allows them to post bad answers as comments without fear of reprisal. We generally don't want any bad content on this website, no matter in what form it is posted.

Also, **comments are not meant to post opinions about the subject matter of the question**. We are a question&answer website, not a discussion forum. We don't want opinionated political discussions to distract from our content. So please don't use comments for posting your personal opinions and/or engaging in political debates. (Note that if you would like to engage in debates with other community members, you can use our chatrooms).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed clarification. Is there anyway to move to chat before a comment chain takes off or do you need to go to chat and open the chat then post it in the comments?

Comment: I would just like to clarify that it was not an answer or discussion. It was giving insight based on an interpretation of Marxism with a recommendation for Marxs philosophy on class conflict thus fulfilling mark 3 on when to comment as it gives insight into the question being asked.

Answer (score 1):

We want to avoid long comment threads in order to maximize the signal-to-noise ratio of content.

The question you commented on, had 32 comments on it, most of which presumably weren't needed, so a moderator decided to migrate the whole thing to chat.  The one comment that's left has a link that should bring you to the chat where comment thread has been migrated.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly *all* comments get deleted here. It's just how this place is run. Ironically, the fact that all comments get deleted seems to encourage more comments (knowing they'll just get deleted anyways)

Comment: <all comments get deleted here> than why am I currently visualizing a comment made in 2012?

Comment: @Federico let me update to clarify for those that read everything literally.

Comment: but it is not even "nearly all". many, could be, but either you provide data or you are just writing a useless hyperbole. Across all SE comments are cleared when needed. Probably here is needed more often, but the deletion is the effect, not the cause.

Comment: There's no arguing comments aren't deleted *way* more here both in terms of quantity and frequency than most other SE sites. In fact, many site are just fine with comments being left up. I'm not arguing that it's right or wrong how it's done here. Just that it's how it's done here. And given the frequency that comments are deleted, and the frequency that people put comments back up leads me to believe that a) either we still have really crappy questions here or b) the comments get replaced because the previous discussion is no longer known.